# Boost Spirit x3 conditional (ternary) operator parser (follow up question)

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

This question is a follow up question for the one in

[Boost Spirit x3 conditional (ternary) operator parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808321/boost-spirit-x3-conditional-ternary-operator-parser)

The original question context did not show (my bad!) the ast attributes and the answer therefore could not take all the moving parts into account. This question now shows how the ast attributes looks like and how the ast is used to evaluate the expression with a symbol table.

The follow up question is therefore that how the correctly spelled ternary conditional should change the ast types and how the conditional and expression interact together (according to my understanding it is now not part of the x3::variant as it is to be removed from primary parser choices)

Here is how the ast attributes and declared symbol definitions look like

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {

struct nil {};
struct unary_op;
struct binary_op;
struct conditional_op;
struct expression;

struct operand : x3::variant<
                 nil
                 , double
                 , std::string
                 , x3::forward_ast<unary_op>
                 , x3::forward_ast<binary_op>
                 //, x3::forward_ast<conditional_op> // conditional_op not here?
                 , x3::forward_ast<expression>
                 > {
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};

struct unary_op {
    double (*op)(double);
    operand rhs;
};

struct binary_op {
    double (*op)(double, double);
    operand lhs;
    operand rhs;
};

/*
struct conditional_op {
    operand lhs;
    operand rhs_true;
    operand rhs_false;
};
*/

struct conditional_op {
    expression lhs;
    // how the exact type is spelled?
    optional<expression, expression> maybe_rhs;
};

struct operation {
    double (*op)(double, double);
    operand rhs;
};

// what is the type of expression ?
struct expression {
    conditional_op conditional;
};

/*
struct expression {
    operand lhs;
    std::list<operation> rhs;
};
*/

} // namespace ast

struct constant_ : x3::symbols<double> {
    constant_() {
        add
            ("e"      , boost::math::constants::e<double>())
            ("pi"     , boost::math::constants::pi<double>())
            ;
    }
} constant;

struct ufunc_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double)> {
    ufunc_() {
        add
            ("abs"   , static_cast<double (*)(double)>(&std::abs))
            ;
    }
} ufunc;

struct bfunc_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    bfunc_() {
        add
            ("max"  , static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&std::fmax))
            ;
    }
} bfunc;

struct unary_op_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double)> {
    unary_op_() {
        add
            ("+", static_cast<double (*)(double)>(&math::plus))
            ("-", static_cast<double (*)(double)>(&math::minus))
            ("!", static_cast<double (*)(double)>(&math::unary_not))
            ;
    }
} unary_op;

struct additive_op_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    additive_op_() {
        add
            ("+", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::plus))
            ("-", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::minus))
            ;
    }
} additive_op;

struct multiplicative_op_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    multiplicative_op_() {
        add
            ("*", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::multiplies))
            ("/", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::divides))
            ("%", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&std::fmod))
            ;
    }
} multiplicative_op;

struct logical_op_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    logical_op_() {
        add
            ("&&", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::logical_and))
            ("||", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::logical_or))
            ;
    }
} logical_op;

struct relational_op_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    relational_op_() {
        add
            ("<" , static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::less))
            ("<=", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::less_equals))
            (">" , static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::greater))
            (">=", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::greater_equals))
            ;
    }
} relational_op;

struct equality_op_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    equality_op_() {
        add
            ("==", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::equals))
            ("!=", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&math::not_equals))
            ;
    }
} equality_op;

struct power_ : x3::symbols<double (*)(double, double)> {
    power_() {
        add
            ("**", static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(&std::pow))
            ;
    }
} power;
```

The more complete grammar and the definition of ast attributes is below (with modifications based on the answer in [Boost Spirit x3 conditional (ternary) operator parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808321/boost-spirit-x3-conditional-ternary-operator-parser))

```
struct expression_class;
struct logical_class;
struct equality_class;
struct relational_class;
struct additive_class;
struct multiplicative_class;
struct factor_class;
struct primary_class;
struct unary_class;
struct binary_class;
struct conditional_class;
struct variable_class;

// Rule declarations

auto const expression     = x3::rule<expression_class    , ast::expression    >{"expression"};
auto const logical        = x3::rule<logical_class       , ast::expression    >{"logical"};
auto const equality       = x3::rule<equality_class      , ast::expression    >{"equality"};
auto const relational     = x3::rule<relational_class    , ast::expression    >{"relational"};
auto const additive       = x3::rule<additive_class      , ast::expression    >{"additive"};
auto const multiplicative = x3::rule<multiplicative_class, ast::expression    >{"multiplicative"};
auto const factor         = x3::rule<factor_class        , ast::expression    >{"factor"};
auto const primary        = x3::rule<primary_class       , ast::operand       >{"primary"};
auto const unary          = x3::rule<unary_class         , ast::unary_op      >{"unary"};
auto const binary         = x3::rule<binary_class        , ast::binary_op     >{"binary"};
auto const conditional    = x3::rule<conditional_class   , ast::conditional_op>{"conditional"};
auto const variable       = x3::rule<variable_class      , std::string        >{"variable"};

// Rule defintions
/* This is a bit of magic to me. Does this definition now say that expression 
   itself is now initializer list constructible from the conditional (which is spelled below)?
*/
auto const expression_def =
    conditional
    ;

/* now ast::conditional_op type should be constructible from an initialization list consisting 
   of of an expression and optional<tuple<expression,expression>> ? How these types should be 
   spelled in the struct? There is a circular reference between expression and conditional :D ? 
*/  
auto const conditional_def =
    logical >> -('?' > expression > ':'> expression)
    ;

auto const logical_def =
    equality >> *(logical_op > equality)
    ;

auto const equality_def =
    relational >> *(equality_op > relational)
    ;

auto const relational_def =
    additive >> *(relational_op > additive)
    ;

auto const additive_def =
    multiplicative >> *(additive_op > multiplicative)
    ;

auto const multiplicative_def =
    factor >> *(multiplicative_op > factor)
    ;

auto const factor_def =
    primary >> *( power > factor )
    ;

auto const unary_def =
    ufunc > '(' > expression > ')'
    ;

auto const binary_def =
    bfunc > '(' > expression > ',' > expression > ')'
    ;

auto const primary_def =
      x3::double_
    | ('(' > expression > ')')
    | (unary_op > primary)
    | binary
    | unary
 // | conditional // by removing the conditional from primary implies the type of x3::variant changes
    | variable
    ;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(
    expression,
    logical,
    equality,
    relational,
    additive,
    multiplicative,
    factor,
    primary,
    unary,
    binary,
    conditional,
    variable
)
```

Here is how the AST is traversed using boost static visitor to evaluate the expression with a variable symbol table

```
namespace ast {

// Evaluator

struct Evaluator {
    using result_type = double;

    explicit Evaluator(std::map<std::string, double> sym);

    double operator()(nil) const;

    double operator()(double n) const;

    double operator()(std::string const &c) const;

    double operator()(operation const &x, double lhs) const;

    double operator()(unary_op const &x) const;

    double operator()(binary_op const &x) const;

    double operator()(conditional_op const &x) const;

    double operator()(expression const &x) const;

  private:
    std::map<std::string, double> st;
};

Evaluator::Evaluator(std::map<std::string, double> sym) 
: st(std::move(sym)) {}

double Evaluator::operator()(nil) const {
    BOOST_ASSERT(0);
    return 0;
}

double Evaluator::operator()(double n) const { return n; }

double Evaluator::operator()(std::string const &c) const {
    auto it = st.find(c);
    if (it == st.end()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Unknown variable " + c);
    }
    return it->second;
}

double Evaluator::operator()(operation const &x, double lhs) const {
    double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.rhs);
    return x.op(lhs, rhs);
}

double Evaluator::operator()(unary_op const &x) const {
    double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.rhs);
    return x.op(rhs);
}

double Evaluator::operator()(binary_op const &x) const {
    double lhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.lhs);
    double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.rhs);
    return x.op(lhs, rhs);
}

double Evaluator::operator()(conditional_op const &x) const {
    return static_cast<bool>(boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.lhs)) 
        ? boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.rhs_true) 
        : boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.rhs_false);
}

double Evaluator::operator()(expression const &x) const {
    double state = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.lhs);
    for (operation const &oper : x.rhs) {
        state = (*this)(oper, state);
    }
    return state;
}

} // namespace ast
```

Comment: Ah I missed the evaluator stuff (I just copied the ast stuff in addition to what I already had). Responding to one comment `optional<expression, expression> maybe_rhs` would be more like `optional<expression> lhs, rhs` or even more accurately `optional<tuple<expression, expression> > lhs_rhs`. Regardless it is going to be clumsy using automatic attribute propagation, which is why I opted for a semantic action for quick results in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the top-level attribute exposed is `expression`, which is, frankly, not representing an expression at all.

Rather, it is representing an artificial unit of expression input syntax, which could perhaps be dubbed "operation_chain".

This is also going to make it hard to use your AST for semantically correct transformations (like e.g. expression evaluation) because crucial information like precedence of operations is not encoded in it.

> In fact, if we're not careful it's very possible that this information - if present in the input - would be lost. I *think* it's possible in practice to go from your AST and reconstruct the operation tree with dependent operations in order of their precedence. But I usually err on the safe side of explicitly modeling the expression tree to reflect the operation dependencies.

That said, the `conditional_op` is not a chaining binary operation, so it doesn't fit the mold. I'd suggest making the "top level" rules expose an `ast::operand` instead (so it can fit the `conditional_op` or `expression` both just fine).

However, due the "lazy" way we detect the conditional, this requires some semantic actions to actually build the proper attributes:

```
auto const conditional_def =
    logical [([](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); })]
    >> -('?' > expression > ':' > expression) [make_conditional_op]
    ;
```

The first semantic action is straight-forward, the second one became large enough to define it out-of-line:

```
auto make_conditional_op = [](auto& ctx) {
    using boost::fusion::at_c;
    x3::_val(ctx) = ast::conditional_op {
        x3::_val(ctx),
        at_c<0>(x3::_attr(ctx)),
        at_c<1>(x3::_attr(ctx)) };
};
```

Still straight-forward but clumsy. Notice that the reason is that we expose different types depending on the presence of the optional branch.

Here's it all put together working:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bace4361b0eef33d)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
//#define DEBUG_SYMBOLS
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {

    struct nil {};
    struct unary_op;
    struct binary_op;
    struct conditional_op;
    struct expression;

    using UnFunc = std::function<double(double)>;
    using BinFunc = std::function<double(double, double)>;

    struct operand : x3::variant<
             nil
           , double
           , std::string
           , x3::forward_ast<unary_op>
           , x3::forward_ast<binary_op>
           , x3::forward_ast<conditional_op>
           , x3::forward_ast<expression> >
    {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    struct unary_op {
        UnFunc op;
        operand rhs;
    };

    struct binary_op {
        BinFunc op;
        operand lhs;
        operand rhs;
    };

    struct conditional_op {
        operand lhs;
        operand rhs_true;
        operand rhs_false;
    };

    struct operation {
        BinFunc op;
        operand rhs;
    };

    struct expression {
        operand lhs;
        std::list<operation> rhs;
    };

} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::expression, lhs, rhs)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::operation, op, rhs)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::conditional_op, lhs, rhs_true, rhs_false)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::binary_op, op, lhs, rhs)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::unary_op, op, rhs)

namespace P {

    struct ehbase {
        template <typename It, typename Ctx>
        x3::error_handler_result on_error(It f, It l, x3::expectation_failure<It> const& e, Ctx const& /*ctx*/) const {
            std::cout << std::string(f,l) << "\n"
                      << std::setw(1+std::distance(f, e.where())) << "^"
                      << "-- expected: " << e.which() << "\n";
            return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
        }
    };

    struct expression_class     : ehbase {};
    struct logical_class        : ehbase {};
    struct equality_class       : ehbase {};
    struct relational_class     : ehbase {};
    struct additive_class       : ehbase {};
    struct multiplicative_class : ehbase {};
    struct factor_class         : ehbase {};
    struct primary_class        : ehbase {};
    struct unary_class          : ehbase {};
    struct binary_class         : ehbase {};
    struct conditional_class    : ehbase {};
    struct variable_class       : ehbase {};

    // Rule declarations
    auto const expression     = x3::rule<expression_class    , ast::operand       >{"expression"};
    auto const conditional    = x3::rule<conditional_class   , ast::operand       >{"conditional"};
    auto const primary        = x3::rule<primary_class       , ast::operand       >{"primary"};
    auto const logical        = x3::rule<logical_class       , ast::expression    >{"logical"};
    auto const equality       = x3::rule<equality_class      , ast::expression    >{"equality"};
    auto const relational     = x3::rule<relational_class    , ast::expression    >{"relational"};
    auto const additive       = x3::rule<additive_class      , ast::expression    >{"additive"};
    auto const multiplicative = x3::rule<multiplicative_class, ast::expression    >{"multiplicative"};
    auto const factor         = x3::rule<factor_class        , ast::expression    >{"factor"};
    auto const unary          = x3::rule<unary_class         , ast::unary_op      >{"unary"};
    auto const binary         = x3::rule<binary_class        , ast::binary_op     >{"binary"};
    auto const variable       = x3::rule<variable_class      , std::string        >{"variable"};

    struct constant_ : x3::symbols<double> {
        constant_() {
            this->add
                ("e"      , boost::math::constants::e<double>())
                ("pi"     , boost::math::constants::pi<double>())
                ;
        }
    } constant;

    struct ufunc_ : x3::symbols<ast::UnFunc> {
        ufunc_() {
            this->add
                ("abs"   , &std::abs<double>)
                ;
        }
    } ufunc;

    struct bfunc_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        bfunc_() {
            this->add
                ("max"  , [](double a,double b){ return std::fmax(a,b); })
                ("min"  , [](double a,double b){ return std::fmin(a,b); })
                ("pow"  , [](double a,double b){ return std::pow(a,b); })
                ;
        }
    } bfunc;

    struct unary_op_ : x3::symbols<ast::UnFunc> {
        unary_op_() {
            this->add
                ("+", [](double v) { return +v; })
                ("-", std::negate{})
                ("!", [](double v) { return !v; })
                ;
        }
    } unary_op;

    struct additive_op_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        additive_op_() {
            this->add
                ("+", std::plus{})
                ("-", std::minus{})
                ;
        }
    } additive_op;

    struct multiplicative_op_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        multiplicative_op_() {
            this->add
                ("*", std::multiplies<>{})
                ("/", std::divides<>{})
                ("%", [](double a, double b) { return std::fmod(a, b); })
                ;
        }
    } multiplicative_op;

    struct logical_op_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        logical_op_() {
            this->add
                ("&&", std::logical_and{})
                ("||", std::logical_or{})
                ;
        }
    } logical_op;

    struct relational_op_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        relational_op_() {
            this->add
                ("<" , std::less{})
                ("<=", std::less_equal{})
                (">" , std::greater{})
                (">=", std::greater_equal{})
                ;
        }
    } relational_op;

    struct equality_op_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        equality_op_() {
            this->add
                ("==", std::equal_to{})
                ("!=", std::not_equal_to{})
                ;
        }
    } equality_op;

    struct power_ : x3::symbols<ast::BinFunc> {
        power_() {
            this->add
                ("**", [](double v, double exp) { return std::pow(v, exp); })
                ;
        }
    } power;

    auto const variable_def = x3::lexeme[x3::alpha >> *x3::alnum];

    // Rule defintions
    auto const expression_def =
        conditional
        ;

    auto make_conditional_op = [](auto& ctx) {
        using boost::fusion::at_c;
        x3::_val(ctx) = ast::conditional_op {
            x3::_val(ctx),
            at_c<0>(x3::_attr(ctx)),
            at_c<1>(x3::_attr(ctx)) };
    };

    auto const conditional_def =
        logical [([](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); })]
        >> -('?' > expression > ':' > expression) [make_conditional_op]
        ;

    auto const logical_def =
        equality >> *(logical_op > equality)
        ;

    auto const equality_def =
        relational >> *(equality_op > relational)
        ;

    auto const relational_def =
        additive >> *(relational_op > additive)
        ;

    auto const additive_def =
        multiplicative >> *(additive_op > multiplicative)
        ;

    auto const multiplicative_def =
        factor >> *(multiplicative_op > factor)
        ;

    auto const factor_def =
        primary >> *( power > factor )
        ;

    auto const unary_def 
        = (unary_op > primary)
        | (ufunc > '(' > expression > ')')
        ;

    auto const binary_def =
        bfunc > '(' > expression > ',' > expression > ')'
        ;

    auto const primary_def =
        x3::double_
        | ('(' > expression > ')')
        //| (unary_op > primary)
        | binary
        | unary
        | constant
        | variable
        ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expression)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(logical)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(equality)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(relational)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(additive)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(multiplicative)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(factor)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(primary)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(unary)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(binary)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(conditional)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(variable)
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {
           "x+(3**pow(2,8))",
           "1 + (2 + abs(x))",
           "min(x,1+y)",
           "(x > y ? 1 : 0) * (y - z)",
           "min(3**4,7))",
           "3***4",
           "(3,4)",
        })
    {
        std::cout << " ===== " << std::quoted(input) << " =====\n";
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        ast::operand out;
        if (phrase_parse(f, l, P::expression, x3::space, out)) {
            std::cout << "Success\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed\n";
        }
        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << "Unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```
 ===== "x+(3**pow(2,8))" =====
Success
 ===== "1 + (2 + abs(x))" =====
Success
 ===== "min(x,1+y)" =====
Success
 ===== "(x > y ? 1 : 0) * (y - z)" =====
Success
 ===== "min(3**4,7))" =====
Success
Unparsed: ")"
 ===== "3***4" =====
3***4
   ^-- expected: factor
Failed
Unparsed: "3***4"
 ===== "(3,4)" =====
(3,4)
  ^-- expected: ')'
Failed
Unparsed: "(3,4)"
```

I feel it should be possible to be

- more elegant ([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil))
- model the expression more semantically

but sadly I lacked the time to work on it, so this is it for the moment :)

Comment: I think this was quite an awesome and elegant answer. Now it compiles, need to test more tomorrow. Big kudos to you!
I was too fixed to the idea that the top level needs to be an expression but now that you say it, it makes total sense for it to be operand. Also nice way of using semantic actions. 

One question though: In make_conditional_op isn’t the attribute of x3::_attr(ctx) optional<tuple<operand,operand>> not tuple<operand,operand>?

Comment: I guess that depends on the precedence. I guessed `-p[action]` would parse as `-(p[action])`, not `(-p)[action]`. And you're welcome :)

Comment: (By the way, I later realized that the issues I sensed w.r.t. precedence in the AST representation are probably moot due to the way the rules are structured. On the flip-side, you might get lots of redundant `expression` nodes in your AST tree. See e.g. using a simple `debug_printer` [all the parentheses which indicate a level of `op_chain` instances](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06b2b694fcd29618) (I decided to rename `expression` -> `op_chain` and `operand` -> `expression` making the names much more natural))

Comment: Hi sehe. I tested this today and I can parse and evaluate quite arbitrary complex expressions (with nested conditionals etc ;-)) with the same `Evaluator` I posted in my question. I also noticed the same as you did, even with a very simple use case such as "1". However I think it should be doable to implement a visitor for AST that returns another "folded" AST that would unwrap   empty `op_chains`. Do you think this is the best approach? Or is it really possible to define the grammar always in an optimal way?

Comment: Regarding error handling on expectation points I would want to throw my own exception types with the formatted error message that is formed on `ehbase::on_error`. I did it by just throwing my own exception from the handler. It seems to work but is this against the "spirit" of Spirit? I tried to find what is the best way for this by reading https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/error_handling.html but it did not answer for my question directly

Comment: Instead of "optimizing" after creating a deeply nested AST, how about using the same approach as with the ternary, like so: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26cb38ef85fc5cf2 Notice I refactored some more things there to result in more accurate and flexible Ast. (Also, subtly, the `op_chain` has disappeared)

Comment: Regarding error handling, no strong opinions (outside the statefulness, keep in mind what happens when your iterator is actually not random-access or even a `spirit::multi_pass_adaptor<>` like in a streaming situation). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57067207/85371 perhaps

Comment: I finally found a moment to actually incorporate the eval part: https://wandbox.org/permlink/aht6xEIhCvPhTDGV
I strived to decouple parsing from eval (good code hygiene). With a trivial amount of work you can let the parser learn the supported functions from an Evaluator implementation: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GpuOcf3pxb0odZBT I hope you see something nice in the many simplifications and even some optimizations I included.

Comment: Hi sehe. Thanks a lot for your effort on this. You provided a lot more than I ever dared to even ask :-) I will definitely be salvaging the simplified grammar and N-ary function concept. It makes sense that the visitor itself says which function names it supports rather than hard coding them into the parser. This fits into my domain very well. Just to let you know what I am doing with this is that I am making dynamically typed domain specific scripting language which needs to be able to parse certain expression on its commands. Depending on the context I then have various visitors of the ast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206499/discussion-between-sehe-and-lauri).